# Decrease size between objects go lang fyne image and text

Tags: go, lang, fyne

for some reason there is so much space between the text and the image, how do i resolve this ??

https://ibb.co/xjwDG6t

this is the code i use to create it with, tried with resize and some diff options from fyne docs but nothing really helps .

```
            text := widget.NewLabel("Storage.plan2learn.dk")
            text2 := widget.NewLabel(dataReturn().Value)
            text3 := canvas.NewImageFromFile("./healthy.png")
            text3.FillMode = canvas.ImageFillContain
            text3.SetMinSize(fyne.Size{Width: 30, Height: 20})
            grid := container.New(layout.NewGridWrapLayout(fyne.Size{Width: 200, Height: 50}), text, text2, text3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `GridWrap` specifies that each item should be 200 wide, so that is probably where the gap is coming from.
If you want them to be up against each other you might want to try `HBox` instead.

Comment: I'll try hbox !

Comment: but ther wierd thing is there is NO gap between text, text0 , but text3 which is an small image 48x48 Px is having much wider space between

Comment: Your use of GridWrap is specifying that every item should be given 200 width. Ones that are smaller will get a bigger gap, ones bigger may overflow. This is special to GridWrap which is designed for things like laying out a file manager where there are lots of items all the same size which should wrap if there are too many.